# Split string into a list, with items of equal length

Tags: python, string, list, split

I have a string (without spaces) which I need to split into a list with items of equal length. I'm aware of the `split()` method, but as far as I'm aware this only splits via spaces and not via length.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx"
string = string.Split(0 - 3)
print(string)

>>> ["abcd", "efgh", "ijkl", "mnop", "qrst", "uvwx"]
```

I have thought about looping through the list but I was wondering if there was a simpler solution?

Comment: @m.wasowski The question you are referring to asks for an iterator, it's slightly different.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
>>> [string[start:start+4] for start in range(0, len(string), 4)]
['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop', 'qrst', 'uvwx']
```

It works even if the last piece has less than 4 characters.

PS: in Python 2, `xrange()` should be used instead of `range()`.

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm, now I've just gt to wait another 4 mins to accept the answer!

Answer (score 3):

How about :

```
>>> string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx'
>>> map(''.join, zip(*[iter(string)]*4))
['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop', 'qrst', 'uvwx']
>>>
```

Comment: Cute but wasteful: the string is decomposed into characters that are later reassembled. Plus, this fails to pick the last characters when the string does not have a length which is a multiple of 4.

Answer (score 2):

or:

```
map(lambda i: string[i:i+4], xrange(0, len(string), 4))
```

Comment: xrange is good. But the map+lambda is not obviously clearer than a list comprehension…

Answer (score 1):

Use the `textwrap` standard library module:

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> textwrap.wrap('abcdefghijklmnopq', 4)
['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop', 'q']
```

Edit: crap, this doesn't work right with spaces. Still leaving the answer here because the last time I had your problem, I was actually trying to wrap text, so maybe others have the same.

Comment: This fails on "Hi!\nOh!\nAh!". In fact, `textwrap.wrap()` is intended for paragraphs that contain words.

Comment: I just noticed, pity.