# Split string into a list, with items of equal length in python 3

Tags: python

I'm looking to split a given string into a list with elements of equal length, I have found a code segment that works in versions earlier than python 3 which is the only version I am familiar with.

```
string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx"
string = string.Split(0 - 3)
print(string)

>>> ["abcd", "efgh", "ijkl", "mnop", "qrst", "uvwx"]
```

When run in python 3 it returns the following error message:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

What changes can I make to make this compatible with python 3?

Comment: this certainly doesn't work in any version of python

Comment: Use `[''.join(t) for t in zip(*[iter(s)]*4)]`

Comment: Its sourced from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656768/split-string-into-a-list-with-items-of-equal-length

Comment: @FrankT ...which is also a duplicate and has the duplicate linked :P

Comment: you can use this code: [s[i:i+4] for i in range(0,24,4)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
split_string_list = [string[x:x+4] for x in range(0,len(string),4)]
```

Try that

Basically what it is a list generated such that it starts with elements 0-4, then 4-8, etc. which is exactly what you want, typecasted into a string

Comment: @ubadub Please dont say like this :( . Actually i forgotted what i edited. I think you have the privilage to accept/deny my edit?

Comment: @itzmeontv it's fine, you're right that it could be formatted better, it just seems kinda nitpickey. Forget it, I overreacted

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no attribute `Split` for strings in **any** version of [python](/questions/tagged/python).
2. If you intended to write `split`, the aforementioned method requires a **character** in **all** versions of [python](/questions/tagged/python)

---

[python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x)

```
>>> string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx"
>>> string = string.split(0 - 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

[python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x)

```
>>> string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx"
>>> string = string.split(0 - 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

#### That said...

You can use the following code to split into equal groups:

```
def split_even(item, split_num):
    return [item[i:i+split_num] for i in range(0, len(item), split_num)]
```

As such:

```
>>> split_even("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 4)
['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop', 'qrst', 'uvwx', 'yz']
>>> split_even("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 6)
['abcdef', 'ghijkl', 'mnopqr', 'stuvwx', 'yz']
>>> split_even("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 13)
['abcdefghijklm', 'nopqrstuvwxyz']
>>>
```

Comment: In the immortal words of the dude: "You're not wrong..." this just isn't an answer :)

Comment: You missed a `)`, and the dupe does it better, but it's an answer now! +0 :)

Comment: Haha :) Will edit, thanks